# Burninate the [cydia] tag

Tags: discussion

[cydia](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cydia) is used for jailbroken iOS devices (iPhone, iPod touch, iPad, etc) in place of the official Apple App Store. Since these portable devices are not really on topic for SU, and Cydia doesn't do anything on a desktop system, I would like to suggest we remove the tag, which only has one closed question

Comment: If it's only on _one_ question, just remove the tag manually.

Comment: @nhinkle How do I do that?

Comment: Edit -> click the little `(x)` on the tag -> save changes...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the tag is on *one* question, of few handful of question, you can always remove the tag from the question by editing it out.

Unused tags are automatically purged from the system,

Comment: Good to know... I can do that